# Changing several variables in methods in C# for Main() to recognize

Tags: c#, non-static

I declared two variables in Main and changed both of them in a non static Method which receives a few variables(including the two I changed) and returns another, but Main doesn't recognize the change to the other variables after I use return();, and the values keep resetting. How can I make it recognize the changes?

```
    string Attack(int Mhp, int Chp, int Cdmg, int Mdmg, string charname)
    {
        string res;
        Mhp -= Cdmg;
        Chp -= Mdmg;
        Console.WriteLine();
        res=charname + "'s Health has been reduced to " + Chp +", and Monster's Health                reduced to " + Mhp;
        return(res);
    }
```

Mhp and Chp remain the same as I declared them in Main();, making my code pointless if the characters' health keeps resetting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sidenote: long variable names don't hurt. Parameters are generally wirten in `camelCase` notation.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
string Attack(ref int Mhp, ref int Chp, int Cdmg, int Mdmg, string charname)
```

When you want to do change in value type inside a procedure, it has to be passed by reference. This is C# trivia - read something on it :)

Answer (score 2):

Integer is a value type, which passed to method by copy, not by reference. You are changing copy and original value stays same. Either pass value types by reference, or create reference type `Character` which will hold integer values, and pass character to this method.

---

```
public class Character
{
    private int health;
    public event Action<Character> HealthChanged;

    public Character(string name, int hp, int cdmg)
    {
        Name = name;
        health = hp;
        Damage = cdmg;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Damage { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAlive { get { return Health > 0; } }

    public int Health 
    { 
        get { return health; }
        private set 
        {
            if (!IsAlive)
                return;

            health = value;

            if (HealthChanged != null)
               HealthChanged(this);
        }
    }

    public void Attack(Character target)
    {
        if (IsAlive)
            target.Health -= Damage;
    }
}
```

This class has event to notify game core about character health changed (consider to notify about healing also). In Main create both characters and subscribe to health changing event. Then start fight:

```
var character = new Character("Bob", 100, 70);
character.HealthChanged += CharacterHealthChanged;

var monster = new Character("Monster", 200, 10);
monster.HealthChanged += CharacterHealthChanged;

while (character.IsAlive && monster.IsAlive)
{
    character.Attack(monster);
    monster.Attack(character);
}
```

Event handler:

```
static void CharacterHealthChanged(Character characer)
{
    if (!characer.IsAlive)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was killed", characer.Name);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0}'s health reduced to {1}", 
                                characer.Name, characer.Health);
}
```

Output

```
Monster's health reduced to 130
Bob's health reduced to 90
Monster's health reduced to 60
Bob's health reduced to 80
Monster is dead
```

Answer (score 1):

primitives are handed over to a function by value, not by reference ... so you are changing a copy of your variable ... the original never sees that change ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly reference them:

```
int something = 5;
CallMethod(ref something);

private void CallMethod(ref int x) {
   x += 10;
}

Console.WriteLine(something); // Output: 15
```

The way you are doing it now will only change the values inside your method but will not reflect these changes to the variable outside of it. Integers are value types which means they will be sent by value. You have to explicitly define them to be sent as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be better to declare Mhp and Chp (or the structure/class containing them) globally in the class. 
If you really want to have them declared in your main, use the ref keyword so that the program will pass to the attack function a reference to your main's var, and not a shallow copy containing the values taken from them at the time the call to attack is being issued

```
string Attack(ref int Mhp, ref int Chp, int Cdmg, int Mdmg, string charname)
```

Note that the first approach I suggested is a lot easier (declaring class-level vars) because that way they will be accessible directly (and not by reference) by any member method of your class.

Cheers